# Summing cell E1 + F1 and putting the answer in E1? Is this possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with my current project. I am trying to add current amount to prior amount for the new month. Summing E1 + F1 and insert the answer in E1. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'I declare variable as double because your values may have decimals
    Dim dbE1 As Double, dbF1 As Double, dbTotal As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'In my opinion is better to pass the values in variables before you change anything in case you want to use them again
        dbE1 = .Range("E1").Value
        dbF1 = .Range("F1").Value
        dbTotal = dbE1 + dbF1

        .Range("E1").Value = dbTotal

    End With

End Sub
```